# Symfony2 updated entity works on dev but not on prod

Tags: symfony

I recently had to add new 'field' to Product in my sonata application so i added it in entity devinition ...

```
/**
 * @var integer $deliveryTime
 */
protected $deliveryTime;

/**
 * Get deliveryTime
 *
 * @return integer $deliveryTime
 */
public function getDeliveryTime()
{
    return $this->deliveryTime;
}

/**
 * @param int $deliveryTime
 */
public function setDeliveryTime($deliveryTime)
{
    $this->deliveryTime = $deliveryTime;
}
```

in ORM

```
<field name="deliveryTime" column="delivery_time"  type="integer"  nullable="true" />
```

in ProductProvider

`$formMapper->add('deliveryTime', 'integer')`

and in all the views

It works perfectly on my local environment but when i moved it to production it doesn't work.
Funny thing is that if i access dev environment on my production server it shows the delivery time for products but on prod environment it doesn't.

I cleared cache with --env=prod option, even physically deleted cache files from both dev and prod folders but it won't help.

Database is not the issue because it wouldn't work on dev env if the reason was database.

Any ideas what else should i do to make it work on prod env? 
(i can switch to dev env without the toolbar but it's not 'nice' approach:)

UPDATE: @moonwave99 yes i did update the database and there's nothing related in app_prod.log

what doesn't work on prod and works on dev:
- showing delivery time for product from the database in product view
- showing/updating delivery time through the admin panel

Comment: Have you run the `doctrine:schema:update` command on production? Besides that, what "does not work"? Have you checked the `prod.log`file?

Comment: did you check your `app/logs/prod.log` ?

Comment: do you have some other cache mechanism ? (memcache, varnish, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was strange - i restarted apache service on production server and now it works.

Comment: I've just had exactly the same thing. Must have been a cache issue that was cleared when apache was restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Try running a few commands,

```
    php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
    php app/console cache:clear
    php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

if that fails re-push your code

and re run above

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You should to reload APC. Prod environment saves doctrine cache in this system.
If you use PHP + Apache - restart apache
If you use PHP-FPM - restart php-fpm.